# How to take Screenshot from ARKit of a particular area in Swift?

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

Means if i have to take snapshot of only a particular area and NOT the whole area then how can i do that?As of right now I am doing this(mentioned below)but it will simply take screenshot of whole area

let screenShot = self.sceneView.snapshot()